# bootstrap datetimepicker not working, displays no javascript errors

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I installed Bootstrap Datetimepicker with NuGet as suggested [here](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Installing/#nuget) Below is html code which is not able to display datetimepicker control. From chrome developer tools I found no issues with the loading of scripts or there is any script errors in the console. Any guess why below code not able to display bootstrap datetimepicker

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" />
  <!-- include your less or built css files  -->
  <!-- 
  bootstrap-datetimepicker-build.less will pull in "../bootstrap/variables.less" and "bootstrap-datetimepicker.less";
  or-->

</head>
<body>
    <form>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
            });
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It would help if you can put this code running somewhere, so we can see it running (or failing)

Comment: @Jav Rok, please find the code running at http://www.makemypublication.com/testdate.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works. What you miss is bootstrap CSS. There's supposed to be a calendar icon next to the input that you click to show it. But the calendar would be also unstyled.

Try to put this on your head:

```
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Hey Man, you saved my day. Thanks a lot worked like charm! not sure why bootstrap.min.css not suggested in this link https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Installing/

Comment: Nice, if you accept the answer as the right one I'll appreciate it :)